# Restoring the Database backup in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. While restoring a database backup I'm getting an error

> Specified cast is invalid

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **How** do you restore the backup? In the GUI, or using a T-SQL script? If script: can you show us the script?

Comment: @marc_s in the GUI..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to .BAK file corruption during FTP transfer (transfer mode is set to ASCII).

> > Always, remember to set FTP transfer mode to BINARY while transferring database .BAK file.

try to do this using TSql...

```
Use Master
Go
RESTORE DATABASE Publications
  FROM DISK = 'C:\Publications_backup_2012_10_15_010004_5648316.bak'
  WITH 
    MOVE 'Publications' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\Publications.mdf',--adjust path
    MOVE 'Publications_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\Publications.ldf'
, REPLACE -- Add REPLACE to specify the existing database should be overwritten.
```

Comment: can u tel whats this "MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\Publications.mdf" in the path.. I am not getting this line..

Comment: I have used the above script, I'm getting this error

Comment: The media family on device 'F:\MaskedCBMS-Keenan\MaskedCBMS-Keenan.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Your Error Suggest  that either You were try to restore higher  version bak file to lower version or Might be Your  backup file is corrupted because of  FTP transfer  mode is set to ASCII

Comment: please check this link might it will help you to understand   http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SBU7/SQL+Server+error+3241+-+The+media+family+on+device+...+is+incorrectly+formed